# Optimizing repeated code

Tags: c#

I have alot of methods who use same line of code:

```
title.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
```

I want to optimize it and just call another function instead create a new font foreach method so I try something like this:

```
void  titleFont()
{
    var font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
    return ;
}
```

and then call as:

```
title.Font = titleFont();
```

But I get

> The name 'titleFont' does not exist in the current context

What am I doing wrong? Regards

Comment: @MichaelEarls I am not the OP.

Comment: @Pepe - Can you edit your post and add more code? Without context, it is difficult to determine how to further assist you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is likely not accessible due to scope. By making it public, it is available to all callers. Also, your method needs to return your font or the `font` variable doesn't get set to anything. The code below replaces `void` with `Font` so that the method itself will return the value of the internal `font` variable upon returning.

```
public Font titleFont()
{
    var font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
    return font;
}
```

Comment: Why does this work?  OP would need to know so they dont make the same mistake again.  Code only answers aren't helpful

Comment: OPs method returns void, your answer returns a `Font`.  Make sure you address that too.

Answer (score -4):

your return type is void, change that to font

```
public Font titleFont()
{
    Font fnt = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
    return fnt ;
}
```

and yes the error is because you are not using the reference properly suppose you have the method in a class f suppose and is non static method then you have to Create object of f class and call that method.

Comment: are you adding the desired reference? if not then add system.drawing

Comment: I think he means moreso that "font" is not a real object

Comment: @user3555836 C# is a case sensitive language.  Your code would not compile

Comment: yes i just copied from the post and made only the bare minimum changes! thought that the community would understand and make those changes.

Comment: You are responsible for your own answer.

Comment: You've cleaned up your code, but your explanation at the bottom doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: i just did! and thank you for reminding me of the fact! why didn't you answer if you are so brilliant!

Comment: @user3555836 We aren't required to answer every question. There's other ways to contribute besides answering. Such as helping curate other answers to ensure the quality of this site remains high.

Comment: oh! you took the high road then! good for you i guess! any ways none of my business! i wanted to help as well and i did! thanks for teaching me the right way to help though! will keep it in mind hence forth.

Comment: @user3555836 we're all being constructive here, can you say the same thing about yourself?

Comment: sorry i was editing my response. but honestly i am new and learning quick! am i not?

Comment: @user3555836 most of your replies come off as sarcastic: `"i just did! and thank you for reminding me of the fact! why didn't you answer if you are so brilliant! "`, `"oh! you took the high road then! good for you i guess!"`.  It looks like you have edited some of those comments to be less sarcastic sounding, but my impression was that you were being unhelpful

Comment: @maccettura thats your thinking then! i honestly just added " i wanted to help as well and i did! thanks for teaching me the right way to help though! will keep it in mind hence forth." and yes i accept i am sarcastic in a very harmless and funny way! i intend no disrespect to any one!

Comment: @maccettura i just removed "the" from the above comment.
hoping you wont be offended about me rectifying my grammatical mistakes now!